# Greedy Algorithm java in map

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, greedy

I'm working on emulator of ATM in java. The overall pattern in project is Command. 
So I have 4 commands - getInfo, deposit,withdraw and exit.

I'm facing problems with an implementation of greedy algorithm in withdrawal method. It should return Map were first Integer is "denomination" and second Integer is "amount" left in ATM after we withdrew.

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> withdrawAmount(int expectedAmount)
```

So it takes expected amount as an argument and has to subtract it from ATM with the least possible amount of bills.

```
   public class CurrencyManipulator
    {
// denominations is a map where each denomination and it's quantity stored
        private String currencyCode;
        private Map<Integer, Integer> denominations = new HashMap<>();

        public String getCurrencyCode()
        {
            return currencyCode;
        }

    public CurrencyManipulator(String currencyCode)
    {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    public void addAmount(int denomination, int count)
    {
        if (denominations.containsKey(denomination))
        {
            denominations.put(denomination, denominations.get(count) + count);
        } else
        {
            denominations.put(denomination, count);
        }
    }

    public int getTotalAmount()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair : denominations.entrySet())
        {
            sum = pair.getKey() * pair.getValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public boolean hasMoney()
    {
        return denominations.size() != 0;
    }

    public boolean isAmountAvailable(int expectedAmount)
    {
        return expectedAmount <= getTotalAmount();
    }

     public Map<Integer, Integer> withdrawAmount(int expectedAmount) throws NotEnoughMoneyException
    {


    }
}
```

So I need this method to return a map or throw exception if amount asked "expectedAmount" is higher then money available in ATM.

If we take $600 it could be - three bills: $500 + $50 + $50 OR $200 + $200 + $200, the preferred option is $500 + $50 + $50
Example, you have to give $600
The ATM has the following bill-count:

500 - 2

200 - 3

100 - 1

50 - 12

The result should be:

500 - 1

100 - 1

This what I came up with:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> withdrawAmount(int expectedAmount) throws NotEnoughMoneyException
    {

        denominations.put(50,1);
        denominations.put(500,1);
        denominations.put(200,3);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        sortedMap.putAll(denominations);
        ArrayList<Integer> bills = new ArrayList<>();
        bills.addAll(sortedMap.keySet());


        int num;

        for (int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++)
        {
            if (bills.get(i) <= expectedAmount)
            {
                num = expectedAmount / bills.get(i);
                map.put(bills.get(i), num);
                expectedAmount -= num * bills.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;
    }
```

It returns the map of needed bills and their quantity.

Now my question is..how do i compare it with the "denominations" map i have and subtract new map from it?

Comment: So, what's the problem? Is it that you don't know what the greedy algorithm means here? Is it that you don't know how to start? What have you tried?

Comment: I've edited my post with some additional information

Comment: You need to know the the available bills before you can perform the withdraw operation right?

Comment: yes, and then, when i know the bills and their quantity stored in "denominations", i have to determine whether an ATM has enough money to process the transaction of "expectedAmount"(else throw new NotEnoughMoneyException). if yes - i pull needed bills from "denominations" and store them in new Map which this method returns.

Comment: I don't think this answers your question, but I would recommend creating a class which is a tuple of the data you're working with (denominations and quantities) because the code you have right now which maintains them in a Map is rather confusing. Then you could just maintain these tuples in a List sorted by denomination and subtract the bills you are choosing as you iterate through your algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your help, people! i think I've managed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working code if someone ever needs it

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> withdrawAmount(int expectedAmount) throws NotEnoughMoneyException
    {


        denominations.put(50,2);
        denominations.put(500,1);
        denominations.put(100,1);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sortedDenominations = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        sortedDenominations.putAll(denominations);
        ArrayList<Integer> bills = new ArrayList<>();
        bills.addAll(sortedDenominations.keySet());


        int num;

        for (int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++)
        {
            if (bills.get(i) <= expectedAmount)
            {
                num = expectedAmount / bills.get(i);
                map.put(bills.get(i), num);
                expectedAmount -= num * bills.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> denominPresent:sortedDenominations.entrySet()){
            int value;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> deominNeeded:map.entrySet()){

                if(denominPresent.getKey().equals(deominNeeded.getKey())){
                    value = denominPresent.getValue()-deominNeeded.getValue();
                    if (value>=0) sortedDenominations.put(denominPresent.getKey(),value);
                    else throw new NotEnoughMoneyException();
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println(sortedDenominations);
        return sortedDenominations;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Will work if you initialize the *denominations* variable using *TreeMap*

```
...
private Map<Integer, Integer> denominations = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
...

public Map<Integer, Integer> withdrawAmount(int expectedAmount) throws NotEnoughMoneyException {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    // calculate denomination map to cash
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int denomination = entry.getKey();
        if (denomination <= expectedAmount) {
            int num = Math.min(expectedAmount / denomination, entry.getValue());
            map.put(denomination, num);
            expectedAmount -= num * denomination;
        }
        if (expectedAmount == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (expectedAmount != 0) {
        throw new NotEnoughMoneyException();
    }

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        denominations.compute(key, (denomination, count) -> {
            return (count == value) ? null : count - value;
        });
    });

    return map;
}
```